# Android method interrupt

Tags: android

If I have a method executing in the UI thread, will this method always run till the end, or can this method be interrupted somewhere in the middle (by anything that sends your activity to the paused state) ?

Thanks!

Comment: If stopping it is so important I would suggest you to move it to Async Task or Thread, with these you may call a cancel and interrupt to stop the execution immediately with onPause method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method will be interrupted by crashes (e.g., unhandled exceptions).

It is not interrupted "by anything that sends your activity to the paused state".

Comment: i would say some calls such as yield or wait (called from within said method) would pause the execution (but are not to be used in the ui thread, though)

Comment: @njzk2: Yes, I am assuming sensible development. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure if I was clear enough. I don't want to interrupt the method. I want it to always run till the end. My question was more like - if the method is running and the user receives a phone call, will this interrupt the method, or will the method run till the end and the call will be shown only after ?

Comment: @MartinPetransky: "if the method is running and the user receives a phone call, will this interrupt the method" -- no. This is covered by the second sentence of my answer. "or will the method run till the end and the call will be shown only after ?" -- the method will run until the end. What happens on the screen is up the OS. Bear in  mind that other apps run in their own processes and have their own main application threads. You will not be called with `onPause()` while you are in the middle of your main-app-thread method, but the other app can still take over the foreground.

Comment: Ok, i thought that your activity is paused immediately after another takes over. Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have put an explicit `sleep()` some where in your code, this can lock the whole UI for some seconds. you cannot `pause a process in android or Java`, you can at the max only `sleep threads.`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to exit the method call in the middle, use "return" keyword. For instance:

```
public void doLengthyCalculation(){
  boolean notRequired = true;
  //Do something...
  //Do something else...
  //Now we need to exit
  if(notRequired == true){
    return; //Anything after this point will not be executed.
  }
  //Some more code which will not be executed if above if statement evaluates to true
}
```

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: Please delete this - it is unrelated to the question